SwiftUI: Bind "binding" variable to child view is not working in iOS 15
I have view ItemsView which contains List and binding "selection" variable selectedItem. ItemsView can be included as child to other views so I need bind binding variable selectedItem from other views.
And it works perfect in iOS 17 but doesn't work in iOS 15 (15.8.2) which my app supports. No errors, no warning but selection doesn't work. When I click on list items they are not selecting and value in "You basic item: ?" is not changing too.
This code works in iOS 17, but doesn't work in iOS 15.
Thanks for advance for your ideas how to solve the issue.
import SwiftUI

struct BindingHierarchyView: View {
    @State var defaultItem: Item?
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Your basic item: ") + Text((defaultItem != nil) ? defaultItem!.rawValue : "?")
            SearchableItemsView(selectedItem: $defaultItem)
        }
        
    }
}

struct SearchableItemsView: View {
    @Binding var selectedItem: Item?
    @State var searchText: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ItemsView(selectedItem: $selectedItem, searchText: $searchText)
                .searchable(text: $searchText)
        }
    }
}

struct ItemsView: View {
    
    @Binding var selectedItem: Item?
    @Binding var searchText: String
    
    @Environment(\.isSearching) private var isSearching
    
    private var filteredItems: [Item] {
        searchText.isEmpty ? Items.allItems : Items.allItems.filter { $0.rawValue.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            List(selection: $selectedItem) {
                ForEach(filteredItems, id: \.self) { item in
                    HStack {
                        Text(item.rawValue)
                    }
                    .id(item)
                    .tag(item)
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: isSearching) { newValue in
                if !newValue {
                    print("Searching cancelled")
                    proxy.scrollTo(selectedItem, anchor: .center)
                }
            }
            .onAppear(perform: {
                proxy.scrollTo(selectedItem, anchor: .center)
            })
        }
    }
}

struct Items {
    static let allItems: [Item] = [.ItemOne, .ItemTwo, .ItemThree]
}

enum Item: String {
    case ItemOne
    case ItemTwo
    case ItemThree
}


Wasn't it a limitation on iOS 15, that selection only worked in edit mode? Anyway - try that,, set .environment(\.editMode, .constant(EditMode.active)) and see if it helps
